# convert a list into a single string consisting with double quotes and separated by comma

Tags: python, string, list, formatting

I have met a problem to convert a list: `list=['1','2','3']` into `' "1","2","3" '`.

My code is:

```
str(",".join('"{}"'.format(i) for i in list))
```

but my output is:
    `"1","2","3"` instead of `' "1","2","3" '`

May I have your suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just add white spaces on both sides of the string?

Comment: Hi Mureinik, I need put both the single quote and white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you don't want to just prepend/append the needed substrings(*the single quote and white space*) to the crucial string. 
Here's a *trick* with `str.replace()` function:

```
lst = ['1','2','3']
result = "' - '".replace('-', ",".join('"{}"'.format(i) for i in lst))

print(result)
```

The output:

```
' "1","2","3" '
```

---

- `"' - '"` - acts as a placeholder

---

Or the same with additional `str.format()` function call:

```
result = "' {} '".format(",".join('"{}"'.format(i) for i in lst))
```

Comment: Not sure why the term *macro-substitution* - there's nothing here that is that. Also why the use of  `.replace('-', ...)` why wouldn't you just use `"' {} '".format(...)` and then it's consisten and not relying on replacing a specific character...

Comment: @JonClements, added as alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['1','2','3', '5']
result = "' - '".replace('-', ",".join('"{}"'.format(i) for i in list)) 
# "' - '" - acts as a placeholder
print(result) # ' "1","2","3","5" '
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['1','2','3']
result = ','.join(map(lambda x: '"{}"'.format(x), lst))
print(result)
```

> ```
> '"1","2","3"'
> ```

I first started out putting it in a DataFrame and extracting to the iobuffer using to_csv.  That seemed overly complex.  The above was the most Pythonic that I could come up with.  I did not need the extra spaces before and after, but you can easily add those by concatenating with plus signs or using a another format() statement.